# Cumulatively merge arrays based on intersection without duplicates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, array-merge

I have data that clusters like so
`[[1, 2, 3], [0, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]]`.
I'd like to merge arrays that share items without duplicates.
For example, the result I'm looking for from the above data would be
`[[1, 2, 3, 0, 4], [6, 7]]`.

My approach is to loop through the arrays, and when an intersection is found, form the union of the two arrays. Here's what I've tried:

```
let clusters = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]];
let len = clusters.length;
let i, j;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)  {
  for (j = i+1; j < len; j++)  {
    if (clusters[i].filter(x => clusters[j].includes(x))) {
      clusters[i] = [...new Set([...this.clusters[i], ...this.clusters[j]])]; // this won't work
    }
  }
}
```

The result is that the clusters array is unchanged. I think this could work if I could find a way to run the union operation recursively (when the intersection condition is met).
Or maybe there's a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Array.reduce`, pushing arrays from `clusters` into sets in the output array or merging if a value already exists in one of the sets in the output, and then converting back from sets to arrays once complete:

```js
let clusters = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [0, 2],
  [2, 4],
  [6, 7]
];

let result = clusters.reduce((c, a) => {
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      if (a.some(v => c[i].has(v))) {
        a.forEach(v => c[i].add(v));
        return c;
      }
    }
    c.push(new Set(a));
    return c;
  }, [])
  .map(s => Array.from(s));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may (I didn't really tested it, take this as an idea to begin your research) work.

You don't really need recursion since you are dealing with just one nesting level. Beware of the bad performance of this if you have a large data set.

```
var a=[[1, 2, 3], [0, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]];

function match(a,b) {
    //if you meant _at least_ one match between two elements
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) if(b.indexOf(a[i])>0) return true;
    return false;
}

function combine(a,b) {
    var c=[];
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) if(c.indexOf(a[i])<0) c.push(a[i]);
    for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++) if(c.indexOf(b[i])<0) c.push(b[i]);
    return c;
}

while(1) {
    var found=false;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        for(var j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
            if(i==j) continue;
            //if a match is found, merge the two elements and start over
            if(match(a[i],a[j])) {
                a[i]=combine(a[i],a[j]);
                a.splice(j,1);
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found) break;
    }
    //repeat until no matches were found
    if(!found) break;
}

console.log(a);
```